# Laravel 7 JSON Response comes out empty

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7, laravel-api

I don't really understand why but whenever I reach this point on my code, the result is blank/empty on Postman

```
        //check if user exists based on email
    $userExistanceCheck = $this->findUser($userResponse['email']);

    if ($userExistanceCheck->getData()->status == 400) {
        //begin user registration. He doesn't exist
        return $this->createUser($userDataArray);
    }else if($userExistanceCheck->getData()->status == 200){
        return $this->responser('user found',$userExistanceCheck->getData(),200); <---Here
    }
```

If I do a dd() the values of my dd and of my responser function will be returned normally.
Am I missing something?

my responser function is located on the same controller, handling my API call for registering the user, if no user is found based on email.

```
    public function responser($message, $data, $status)
    {
        $contentType = 'application/json';
        $xrequest = 'XMLHttpRequest';
        $responseData = array(
            'message' => $message,
            'data' => $data,
            'status' => $status);
        return response()->json($responseData)->header('Content-Type', $contentType)->header('X-Requested-With', $xrequest);
    }
```

The result should be something like:

> User found, $USER_DATA, 200

It might be important to note that I use my responser function for pretty much every response every function makes on my controller. I don't know if that can be an issue. If it is, please let me know why.

Comment: Why do you need to set so much things when you could just do `return response()->json($responseData);` ? You are sort of doing what the framework is doing behind scenes... You need to read more documentation.

Comment: I was requested to have a similar output each time for my front end. So I thought instead of using response()->json (which I do inside responser) I would only return they Information the front end needs

Comment: No problem about it, you can use [`API Resources`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-resources#introduction) if you want to stick more to the framework instead of re inventing the wheel, maybe it will still solve your issue and you will not have to create something from the ground up.

Comment: Pretty much I ended up resolving the issue with a short discussion with the front end developer. He will provide me with the required response data and I will provide them in a way that is needed in order for his application to work. Reinventing the wheel was not my thing, but I had a deadline to catch